# Getting return value of inner function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Here is my code i want alert to give (some data) value. which is of inner function it give undefined value

```
alert(f1());
function f1(){
  f2(function (){
    return "some data";    
  });
}
function f2(f4){
  // some code
}
```

visit : https://jsfiddle.net/dvdhyttr/8/

i want alert get value (some data).
but getting undefined.

Comment: You have to be more descriptive about what you want, the question is unintelligible. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dvdhyttr/11/) what you want?

Answer (score 1):

## Two main issues

- Missing return within the function `f1`
- Within function `f2` you need to return the result of calling the function `f4`.

```js
alert(f1());

function f1() {
  return f2(function() {
    return "some data";
  });
}

function f2(f4) {
  return f4()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the return values of the functions to variables in the outer function and return them, all the way up to `alert(f1());`.

```js
alert(f1());

function f1() {
  const resultOfF2 = f2(function() {
    return "some data";
  });
  return resultOfF2;
}

function f2(f4) {
  return f4();
  // some code
}
```